# can we use object properties and method in an array?

Tags: javascript

As I am a beginner and I saw few videos on youtube they are saying basically everything is an object even an array also so I just want to know can we  use object properties and methods in an array

Comment: `arr.push()` is using an array method. `arr.length` is an array property. You *could* add your own methods and properties but most of the time it's a bad idea.

Comment: Yes. Indeed, arrays are objects, so you can do `[1, 2, 3].length` (property) and get `3`, or `[1, 2, 3].push(4)` (method) and update your array

Comment: What is your actual question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: [JavaScript “Associative Arrays” Considered Harmful](https://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed an `Array` is a particular type of object:

```js
const arr = [];

console.log(typeof arr); // object

console.log(arr instanceof Array); // true (This particular object is an instance of Array)

console.log(typeof arr.push); // function (Array method)

console.log(typeof arr.length); // number (Array property)
```